# React/Redux cannot read property "currentOpportunities" of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having trouble with my Redux mapStateToProps function throwing an error saying that state.currentOpportunities is undefined. The weird thing about this is that the initial State that is defined in the organizationReducer can only be reached under state._root.entries[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZKnK.png).organization.currentOpportunity rather than by state.organization.currentOpportunity when I console.log I console.log state in the main index.js file

[Console.log(States)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZKnK.png)

Main App.js file

```
const initialState = {}
const history = createHistory();
const store = configureStore(initialState, history);
const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('app');

const render = messages => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <LanguageProvider messages={messages}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </LanguageProvider>
    </Provider>,
    MOUNT_NODE,
  );
};
```

organizationReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    currentOpportunities: [],
    expiredOpportunities: []
};

export default function (state=initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_ORGANIZATION_OPPORTUNITIES:
            return {...state, data: action.payload}
        case FETCH_CURRENT_OPPORTUNITIES: 
            return{...state, currentOpportunities: action.payload}
        case FETCH_EXPIRED_OPPORTUNITIES: 
            return{...state, expiredOpportunities: action.payload}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

My root reducer file

```
export default function createReducer(injectedReducers) {
  return combineReducers({
    organization: organizationReducer,
    ...injectedReducers
  })
}
```

index.js file

```
const mapStatetoProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state)
  return {
    currentOpportunities: state.organization.currentOpportunities,
    expiredOpportunities: state.organization.expiredOpportunities
  };
}

export default connect(mapStatetoProps, actions)(OpportunitiesPage);
```

Does anyone know what might be happening here?

Comment: can you access organization reducer at all? I mean can you inspect it with Redux-dev-tools, to see what is inside it?

Comment: I checked Redux-dev-tools and it looks like under @@init under the state tab, it is showing  organization initialized values for currentOpportunities and expiredOpportunities as the empty arrays from the reducer.

Comment: @riku12764, what's the structure of your `action.payload`? perhaps you also want to double check why there's a `data` key in `FETCH_ORGANIZATION_OPPORTUNITIES`.

Comment: what is inside you injectedReducers?

Comment: @George.S, Currently there's nothing inside of injectedReducers (just a placeholder until I get it working on the most basic level)

Answer (score -1):

`state.organization.currentOpportunity` is undefined because state is an immutable map and you try to access its field like it's an object. <sup>[1](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js#the-case-for-immutability)</sup>

You must update your reducer logic to use the immutable API where you merge objects *e.g.*

```
   case FETCH_ORGANIZATION_OPPORTUNITIES:
        return state.merge({data: action.payload})
```

Or convert from Immutable data structures to mutable javascript object. e.g.

```
  stateObject = state.toJS()
  return {
      currentOpportunities: stateObject.organization.currentOpportunities,
      //...
```

Since it can lead to a bit of hassle tracking what the instance of an object in state, I suggest sticking with either Immutable data structures or mutable Javascript objects in your component state.

Here is mapStateToProps using Immutable Map API. <sup>[2](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js#nested-structures)</sup>

```
  return {
      currentOpportunities: state.getIn(['organization', 'currentOpportunities'])
      //...
```

Comment: `...` is the [object spread operator](https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator). the return of `mapStateToProps` is a new object so it doesn't modify `state` at all when `props` is used within the component. thus, this doesn't answer the question directly and is only suggesting other library to use.

Comment: @codekaizer I'm not suggesting another library to use. The library is already being used but the OP seems to confuse Javascript object with an immutable map instance. I have advised OP to stick to either using Javascript object in state or do with immutable map object.

Comment: Hi @OluwafemiSule, I tried your suggestions above, but I am getting the same errors as before. From what I can tell, it seems as though the mapStatetoProps is happening before the actions can run at all. Still not sure what is the issue though